# How to create a User class for Flask-Login when using dynamodb?

Tags: python, flask, amazon-dynamodb, flask-login

I am following the tutorial at https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-authentication-to-your-app-with-flask-login for adding register/login features to a flask app, which uses `Flask-Login` with an SQLite database (using `flask_sqlalchemy`). As such, it has code like the following for initializing the SQLite database (from **init**.py):

```
db = SQLAlchemy()
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '9OLWxND4o83j4K4iuopO'
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///db.sqlite'

    db.init_app(app)
```

And then creates a `User` class (as is required by `Flask-Login`) like this:

```
from flask_login import UserMixin
from . import db

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True) # primary keys are required by SQLAlchemy
    email = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(100))
    name = db.Column(db.String(1000))
```

However, I want to store user information in a dynamodb table, not a SQLite table. How then should I write the `User` class? I want each `User` to have an `email`, `password` and `name` property like in this tutorial (along with other properties/methods required at https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#your-user-class as is handled by `UserMixin`), but am unsure how to write the class when using dynamodb.

Comment: As dynamodb is nosql, you can't use it with sqlalchemy afaik. There are other alternative though such as [Pynamodb](https://pynamodb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and [flask-dynamodb](https://flask-dynamo.readthedocs.io/)

Comment: Also check [this](https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/dynamodb-python-sqlalchemy.rst) out. It offers a paid driver for dynamodb which can be used with sqlalchemy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote the User class simply as follows:

```
class User(UserMixin):
    def __init__(self, id, email, name, password):
        self.id = id
        self.email = email
        self.name = name
        self.password = password
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the User class from ZhouW and you will also need a custom user_loader. This here should work:

```
class User(UserMixin):
    def __init__(self, id, email, password):
        self.id = id
        self.email = email
        self.password = password

@login_manager.user_loader
def loader(user_id):
    response = table.query(
            KeyConditionExpression=Key('id').eq(user_id))
    
    if response["Count"] == 0:
        return
    user = User(id=response['Items'][0]["id"], email=response['Items'][0]["email"], password=response['Items'][0]["password"])
    return user
```

Will need a table first, connect something like this:

```
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('users')
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key
```